# VBA: How read a .txt-File and put a string into label

Tags: vba, save, load, txt

I'am new at VBA (no Excel). My problem is...

I want to read a .txt-File from a path named "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Unterlagen\Datei.txt" and put the data from a line into a label. This for many lines.

For example:

The .txt-file named "Datei.txt" contains product data like this:

CPU 2000GHZ

Radeon 550

Power Supply 500Watt

Now I want to save the single lines into a string and show them into a label.

Kind regards Marc

read .txt write into label

Comment: Your question requires more details to answer. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to clarify what you've tried and what specific issues you're having.

Comment: Why you add `visio` tag?

Comment: @Surrogate: Sorry, Stackoverflow wants me to add one programm, in this case it could be visual studio.